# use string_split on json filter

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm trying to use the `string_split` function in my `where` clause to split the values from `json` filter and create `IN` clause. The query should return the values found, otherwise return everything.

Filter:

```
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Filter=N'{
    "objectName": "Object2"
}'
```

The following query, will do exactly what I want, if I only specify one `objectName`.

```
...
AND (c.objectName IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.objectName') IS NULL OR c.objectName= ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.objectName'),c.objectName))
```

But if I change my `Filter` to contain `,` separated values:

```
SET @Filter=N'{
    "objectName": "Object1, Object2"
}'
```

and use `string_split` function to read those values, it's not liking the `string_split` function in the `where` clause. I believe my `syntax` is wrong.

```
AND (c.objectName IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.objectName') IS NULL OR c.objectName IN 
string_split(ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.objectName'),c.objectName), ','))
```

Does `json_value` needs to be casted to `varchar` first?

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is a table value function. If you want it in the `WHERE` you need to include it in a sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test, however, this will (probably) get you what you are after:

```
  AND (c.objectName IS NULL
  AND  JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.objectName') IS NULL 
   OR  c.objectName IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.objectName'),c.objectName), ',')))
```

Like I stated above, `STRING_SPLIT` is a TVF, you can't just reference it in the `WHERE`. It needs to be inside a subquery, or in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, based on your comment. Thank you, it worked!